Debugging xkb layout under wayland
I have a custom layout, made with xkb, that I made back when I used X11. This ported to Wayland just fine.
Now I'm trying to make improvements to the layout. Testing my layout under X11 was a matter of using xkbcomp mylayout.xkb $DISPLAY. Of course, under Wayland, this only affects XWayland, meaning not most of my desktop, making it really difficult to test the layout.
Of course I can install the new version of the layout and log out and in again, but to iterate and test this is extremely impractical.
How can I apply my layout immediately under Wayland so I can iterate and test my changes ? My google searches have come up empty. I'm using KDE if this makes a difference.

I think it works to install the layout, then change the keyboard layout through the desktop environment. So add another layout, install, then change to that layout and back.
Also, to test, essentially using XWayland is fine. Use some X11 only app like emacs or chrome, xkbcomp ... $DISPLAY which warns that it installs it against XWayland, but then it does take effect in the X11 app.
It's not all perfect, but it's sufficient to debug I think.
